# Fire overlaying smoke bug

Tags: smoke-simulation, fire

i’m having a really bad time trying to follow one of Blender Guru’s tutorials. in his fire and smoke cycles tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-zK7Bu8cAI) his smoke particles appear realistically in front of the fire when played in the viewport. Mine however always has the fire rendered completely in front of the smoke, no smoke can be seen in front of the flames, this is especially apparent when viewed from the top down.

Does anybody know what could be causing this? He is using blender 2.73 whereas I am using 2.79, could something have changed there?

Here is his fire

[image]

and here is mine

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What do you have the smoke set to?  It could be that his is set to smoke+fire when yours is set only to fire.  This setting is under the domain settings, the first setting on the right